# If the flerken ate the tesseract then why did it not get powers?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

In *Captain Marvel,* they manage to get the Tesseract, which is the Space Stone, and Fury refused to take it.

Goose the flerken swallowed it, but did not get powers from it.

Why?

Comment: Nobody in the whole MCU EVER gehts any power from simply touching an infinity stone in any of the 21 other movies... why should the flerken?

Comment: no but the flerkin cunsumed it

Comment: So what.... if you eat a battery: can you shoot lightning like Thor does? What fact do you base your question on, that eating a stone does anything to your body?

Comment: @TorstenLink umm... Guardians of the Galaxy, Quill touches the power stone & gets power

Comment: @KharoBangdo not permanently, he doesn't.

Comment: @KharoBangdo Quill touched the **stone**, Goose had contact with the tesseract

Comment: @Vishwa my reply was in relation to "Nobody ever in whole 21 movies" comment which isn't technically correct. You are right. One is stone, another is tessarect

Answer (score 3):

Touching (or even swallowing) the Tesseract does not grant powers to the person holding the construct as seen in multiple instances in multiple MCU movies.

---

### Notably, Captain Marvel did not get her powers from the Tesseract.

The powers are obtained when she absorbed the energy from the exploding light-speed drive installed in her jet fighter after it crashed.

The drive engine was *based* on Tesseract energy but not dependant on it.

The drive and Tesseract are not the same. The drive was destroyed when Carol shot it (and gained powers from the explosion)...the Tesseract was **still in orbit in Mar-Vell's laboratory**.

[image]

---

<sup>Part of the confusion may lie in that when Yon-Rogg asks about the location of the "core" at the crash site, Carol asks "You mean that core?" and shoots the engine.</sup>

<sup>Carol, at this point, **doesn't know the difference** between the engine and the core/Tesseract so it's a natural mistake to make.</sup>

Comment: actually the tessarakt is the core that captain marvel got her powers from

Comment: captain marvel did get her powers frm the tesseract

Comment: @LandonRouiller Okay, **stop right here!** You can disagree with the answer and explain why. But stop claiming people didn't watch the movie. That's about the least constructive thing you can do on an answer. And stop calling people names or **you** will be blocked by *everyone else*.

Comment: well i watched the extended version but did u

Comment: @PaulieD still, the engine was powered by the tesseract somehow, isn't it? and question seems to be abuot Goose, not Carol.

Comment: @Vishwa No..the engine is *based* on Tesseract tech not powered by it.